# KDB Is there a way to save a chained RDBs data down to disk at end of day?

Tags: kdb

I have a KDB tickerplant setup with one RDB containing a trade and quote table subscribed to the tickerplant then another chained RDB containing an aggregation table that is performing various functions on the trade and quote data and publishing back to the tickerplant. Is there any way to save this data down rather than have it all flushed out at end of day?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you use the `.u.end` function.

Every tickerplant subscriber will have `.u.end` triggered at end of day when the tickerplant does its end of dy rollover. Within that function (which contains one parameter, the date which has just passed) you can create the logic to save down your table.

It sounds like you already have some sort of .u.end function in place which is flushing the table. So you will have to make sure to retain the existing behaviour along with the adding the savedown logic. The default `.u.end` function for a vanilla RDB can be seen here: https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb-tick/blob/master/tick/r.q
You might be able to use that or some variant of that.

Comment: I have a Trade and Quote RDB, and Aggregation RDB and an event processor that calculates various aggregations from the trade and quote table. I can only see this aggregation data when I open a handle to the event processor. All these processes have the following .u.end;

.u.end:{t:tables`.;
        t@:where `g=attr each t@\:`sym;
        .Q.hdpf[`$":",.u.x 1;hsym `$"/Users/*****/*****/HDB";x;`sym];
        @[;`sym;`g#] each t;};

when this is not present in the event processor code only trade and quote are saved down and when it is only the aggregation table is saved down

Comment: You might also have to manage what tables are in which instances because your `.u.end` code is taking *all* tables (aka ```tables`. ```) in both instances. If instance A has tables trade and quote (with data) and instance B has tables trade (empty), quote (empty) and aggregated (with data) then the second instance would end up writing down the blank trade and quote tables when it should only be writing down the aggregated table. I suspect this is your issue